# Cannot assign calculation to this value

Tags: java, variables, keyword

I want a placeholder value to hold the answer to a calculation, however the compiler doesn't like it.

Here is my code..

```
float valueOne = Float.parseFloat(txtOne.getText());
float valueTwo = Float.parseFloat(txtTwo.getText());
float valueThree = Float.parseFloat(txtThree.getText());
float final = valueOne+valueTwo+valueThree; // this line is bringing errors
```

Would really appreciate it if you could help me out.

Comment: float var= valueOne+valueTwo+valueThree;
It should now work

Comment: "the compiler doesn't like it" and "this line is bringing errors" doesn't tell us *nearly* as much as the exact compiler error. In future, please specify *exactly* what's wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that `final` is a reserved keyword in Java.  You cannot use it as a variable name.  Just rename your last variable to something like `finalValue` and it will compile fine.

```
float valueOne = Float.parseFloat(txtOne.getText());
float valueTwo = Float.parseFloat(txtTwo.getText());
float valueThree = Float.parseFloat(txtThree.getText());
float finalValue = valueOne+valueTwo+valueThree;
```

Here is a list of [keywords in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

Answer (score 3):

`final` is a keyword. Try changing your `float final` to another name like `float finalAnswer`

Answer (score 1):

It is because you use the keyword final.

Change your name

```
float valueOne = Float.parseFloat(txtOne.getText());
float valueTwo = Float.parseFloat(txtTwo.getText());
float valueThree = Float.parseFloat(txtThree.getText());
float finalHolder = valueOne+valueTwo+valueThree; // No more errors
```

Answer (score 1):

`final` is a reserved keyword in java you can not use it as variable name.